# How to use the OR condition for 4 variables in Helm

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm

The below condition(for 4 variables) is giving me an error when chart is deployed

```
{{ if not ( or (or .Values.firstBoolean .Values.secondBoolean) (or .Values.thirdBoolean .Values.fourthBoolean)) }}
```

However, using the below condition for 3 variables works fine

```
{{ if not (or .Values.firstBoolean (or .Values.thirdBoolean .Values.fourthBoolean)) }}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works fine. Are you sure all the four variables are defined in values file? What error are you seeing

Comment: I think you can pass all four values to a single `or` call, which can simplify the logic.